# How to invoke an event automatically when a function is called?

Tags: c#, .net, events, .net-3.5

I have this kind of code:

```
public class Foo
{
  public SomeHandler OnBar;

  public virtual void Bar()
  {
  }
}
```

Foo is a base class and therefor other classes might inherit from it.
I would like the `OnBar` event to always be fired when `Bar()` is called even if it's not called explicitly inside Bar.
How can it be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A common pattern is to have a non-virtual method that will do what you want that calls a virtual method.  Subclasses can override the inner method to change the functionality, but the public method can be non-virtual on always raise the event first.

```
public class Foo
{
    public SomeHandler OnBar;

    public void Bar()
    {
        if (OnBar != null)
        {
            OnBar(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        BarImpl();
    }

    protected virtual void BarImpl()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically an implementation of the template method pattern + 1

Comment: So this is the best way? In C++ I would use bind() to create a new function out of the event calling function and the original function.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you can't. Not with what Microsoft gives you out of the box.

That said, take a look at "aspect oriented programming" in .NET. Google that, you might get something useful.

**Added:** The standard way would be to raise the event in the `Bar()` method and then require all derived classes to call the base implementation. But you can't enforce it.

Comment: So in which way would you "require" that the device class calls the base implementation? In the coding guidelines or the unit tests?

Comment: @carllacan - Woohoo! Congratulations, you found a 13 years old answer! :) Let's see... I guess that coding guidelines are the right place. Can't really enforce it in the unit tests either. That said, I like the approach in the accepted answer and would probably do that myself.

Answer (score 1):

first of all the code you provided will not compile.
virtual functions must have a body.

To ensure the event is fired you can do something like this.

```
public class Foo
{
  public SomeHandler OnBar;

  public void Bar()
  {
     OnBar();  (check for nulls)
     ProtectedBar();
  }

  protected virtual ProtectedBar()
  {
  }
}
```

Comment: You are correct. However that doesn't matter in this case. It was just to demonstrate that the function can be overriden. I don't know why you were downvoted. I upvoted to balance.

Comment: The code you've provided won't compile either - your virtual function has no return type and your comment isn't a comment.

Comment: Dan Puzey: just followed the question style :P

Answer (score 0):

As Vilx- said, I guess the better way to do this kind of stuff is to use Aspect Oriented Programming.

This would help you with the "entangled code" (ie. calling an event in a method that shouldn't have this responsibility) and "scattered code" (ie. calling the same event in a lot of methods, duplicating your code) problems.

You should take a look at [postsharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/download), it has a free community edition.